# Can't implement sweet alert 2 with laravel 5.6. What's the issue with this code?

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5.6, sweetalert2

I want to perform the delete operation with sweetalert2. But after clicking the confirm button nothing is happening. Form is not submitted. What's the error i'm getting?

```js
function deleteTag(id) {
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
    buttonsStyling: false,
    reverseButtons: true
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('delete-form-' + id).submit();
    } else if (
      // Read more about handling dismissals
      result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
    ) {
      swal(
        'Cancelled',
        'Your data is safe :)',
        'error'
      )
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-fab btn-icon" type="button" onclick="deleteTag({{ $tag->id }})"><i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</button>

<form id="delete-form-{{ $tag->id }}" action="{{ route('admin.tag.destroy',$tag->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
  @csrf @method('DELETE')
</form>
```

I got this console error after selecting confirm delete button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhGNN.png)

Comment: Which version of SweetAlerts you using?

Comment: SweetAlert2 version 7.26.11

Comment: I just tried it in a fiddle and it's working just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/nt6fsz5q/2/

Comment: But it's not working in my side. :(